# Pass LIST object by Rest API Client to Web API 2 using JSON

Tags: asp.net, rest, web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem in pass data list from Client to the Web API 2 by JSON.
Here are my code samples

**Client**

```
string RestUrl = "http://***SrviceUrl***/api/InvoiceHeader/{0}";

var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, string.Empty));

List<InvItem> myList = new List<InvItem>(Common.invitems);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");           
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
response = await client.PutAsync(uri ,content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
         Debug.WriteLine(@"successfully saved.");
       }
```

**Web Service - Controller class**

```
    [HttpPut]
    [BasicAuthentication(RequireSsl = false)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(string item)
    {
        List<InvItemToSave> myList = new List<InvItemToSave>();
        myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InvItemToSave>>(item);

        try
        {
            todoService.InsertInvoiceDetail(myList);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return base.BuildErrorResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ErrorCode.CouldNotCreateItem.ToString());
        }

        return base.BuildSuccessResult(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
```

when i try to pass single data object to same controller it works fine.
but for LIST objects it returns error code.

> StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed'

I tried to pass exact same * list content* through third party [REST client](https://install.advancedrestclient.com/#/install) . It returned success code.

Comment: You are doing a PutAsync into a HttpPost action.

Comment: Yes. my bad. I changed it to [HttpPut] still error occured. thank you jaliya

//===I also updated my above code==//

Comment: Saw another issue, updated the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `PutAsync` into a `HttpPost` action. Your api URL looks incorrect as well, should be,

```
http://***SrviceUrl***/api/InvoiceHeader
```

and action should be,

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(List<InvItem> items)
```

Comment: Cannot Implement. because 'items' is converted to json string

Comment: "***SrviceUrl***/ is just a comment.", that's funny. I meant the argument "{0}" :)

I am not sure what you meant cannot implement.

Comment: no man i cant expose my service url to outside thats why i name as service url not in my code.
in my code its a IP number.

List<InvItem> items return error from
myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InvItemToSave>>(item);

because json DeserializeObject need string value not a list

Comment: Oh, you don't have to deserialize anymore.

Comment: seriously? but its a string no?

I mean JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myList) in client side give me a string

Comment: Your Put action with get list of InvItem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165194/discussion-between-supun-liyanaarachchi-and-jaliya-udagedara).

Comment: it works like a miracle. thank you  "Jaliya Udagedara"